# Why EnumMap constructor needs class argument?

Tags: java, enums

EnumMap class constructor needs class as the argument. Most of the times K.class passed as the argument. I am still not getting what is the reason for accepting this as argument instead of deducing from K.

Thanks
-- pkc

Answer (score 9):

[Tom's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4725/tom-hawtin-tackline) answer is correct, but to address your other point: the reason this information can't just be deduced from the type parameter, `K`, is due to [type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Answer (score 5):

The implementations of `EnumMap` needs metainformation about the `enum`, in particular the number of values. The `Class` object provides this information (IMO it would have been better to go for a specific enum descriptor type). If you don't have the `Class` available, you can always use `HashMap` at some penalty. I guess you could create a growable/uncommitted `EnumMap`-like `Map`.

Comment: the HashMap can't be empty, but it's fine if it contains just some elements and not the full keyUniverse.

Answer (score 2):

The `Map` thus knows all possible keys. It's called (internally) the `keyUniverse`. The comments says:

> All of the values comprising K.  (*Cached for performance*)

Answer (score 2):

As others point out generics are a compiler feature. The jvm has no real support for generics itself. This means that the generic information cannot be used at runtime.

For the `EnumMap<K extends Enum>` this means that you get a `EnumMap<Enum>` at runtime without any information about the K. This limitation of java generics can be worked around by passing the classes of the Generic arguments to a constructor as the class objects still exist at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Generics is a compile time feature, however this K class is needed at runtime, something generics won't do in this case.